# Arduino: LCD won't turn off

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

a few days ago I started working with the Arduino. I've set up a small project with a DHT22 to read the temperature and humidity and write it to an LCD. That works without a problem. Now I want to only turn on the backlight of the LCD when I press a button. That mostly works too:

```
void loop() {

  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTONPIN);

  currentMillisScreen = millis();
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    screenOn = true;
    lcd.backlight();
  }

  // DHT22 related code in here

  if (currentMillisScreen - previousMillisScreen >= SCREEN_ON_TIME) {
    previousMillisScreen = currentMillisScreen;
    screenOn = false;
    lcd.noBacklight();
  }
}
```

The problem is that with this code is that the Backlight won't always stay on for exactly 5 seconds. I thought putting the `currentMillisScreen = millis()` in the following if-Statement would fix it:

```
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  currentMillisScreen = millis();
  screenOn = true;
  lcd.backlight();
 }
```

But if I do that, the Backlight won't turn off again and I don't understand why.

Comment: how is the button wired? do you have a pull-down circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating `currentMillisScreen` in the loop and that is your problem. You just need to find different between currentTime (equal to `millis()`) and previous time that light turned on and if it reaches above the threshold then turn it off. Something like this:

```
#define SCREEN_ON_TIME 5000
bool screenOn = false;
void setup()
{
    //setup
}
void loop()
{

    buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTONPIN);

    if (buttonState == HIGH)
    {
        previousMillisScreen = millis();
        lcd.backlight();
        screenOn = true;
    }

    // DHT22 related code in here

    // if time passed above SCREEN_ON_TIME after we turned on light
    if ((screenOn) && (millis() - previousMillisScreen >= SCREEN_ON_TIME))
    {
        lcd.noBacklight();
        screenOn = false;
    }
}
```